# How to update the order email id from admin in Magento2

Tags: magento2, orders

I want to update the order email id from the admin when you see the order detail, note I don't want to update the customer email id, Just want to update the email address for order only.

Comment: Goto sales_order and sales_order_grid table and update the email ids for particular order.

Comment: I want to edit the email from admin not using the custom query

Comment: There is no such feature available in magento

Answer (score 2):

Here is step by step guide to achieve the above -:

Step 1 : Go to your phpMyAdmin or sqlyog for your Magento 2 store database

Step 2 : Run the following query against your Magento 2 store database

```
update sales_flat_order set customer_email='correct_email_address@abc.com' 
where customer_email='wrong_email_address@abc.com' 
and increment_id='100000003'
```

**Please take back up before running any delete / update / insert statements against your live database**

The above will work for limited amount of requests you get to update or modify email address from your customers.

But if you get a lot of requests or you are not familiar with phpMyAdmin or sqlyog then we would highly recommend you to use the following module as this module allows you to edit email address via admin interface.

https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento2-update-order-email-address.html

Answer (score 0):

Access your database table sales_order_grid  and update the customer_email field of the required record.

Execute the below query on your database to achieve the same.

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order SET customer_email = 'xxxx@xxx.com' 
WHERE increment_id = 'xxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this cheaper and fully [verified solution](https://marketplace.magento.com/magekwik-module-editorderemail.html) by magento team